# Error when create empty dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create an empty dataframe:

```
predict_data <- data.frame("predict_class" = as.numeric(),
                            "predict_score" = as.numeric(),
                            "actual_class" = as.numeric())
```

> Error in as.numeric() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You should use `numeric()` instead of `as.numeric()`

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem in R 3.3.0

Comment: I am using R 3.3.0. Quite strange. Let's me test again.

Comment: works fine with 3.2.x

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
      data.frame(...,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

since it is

```
     stringsAsFactors=TRUE;
```

in default :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
predict_data <- data.frame(predict_class = as.numeric(0),
  predict_score = as.numeric(0),
  actual_class = as.numeric(0))
```

If you know the size you can speed up if you put the size number instead of 0.